# datatable filters update on the fly

Tags: shiny, dt

In the basic example below I would like to have all filters updated every time user add a filter.

ui :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
      DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
    )
  )
)
```

Server :

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(var1 = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)), var2 = c("x","y","x","z","x","s"), var3 = c(1:6))

output$dt <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(df, filter = 'top')
  })

})
```

When no filter applied :

[image]

When I apply filter on var1 to "A", `s` and `z` still remain in the suggested label in var2 filter even if there are no value to `s` or `z`

[image]

Comment: Would a solution with `selectInput` dropdowns work or you only want to use the column filters?

Comment: This is my actual workaround, I would like to know if there is a full DT solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do if I use `selectInput` for the filters. May not be the best solution, but it has always worked for me.

Code for `ui.r`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,selectizeInput("var1", label = "Var 1", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE)),
    column(4,selectizeInput("var2", label = "Var 2", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE)),
    column(4,selectizeInput("var3", label = "Var 3", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE)),
    column(4,DT::dataTableOutput("dt")
    )
  )
)
```

Code for `server.R`

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  df <- data.frame(var1 = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)), var2 = c("x","y","x","z","x","s"), var3 = c(1:6))

  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'var1', choices = sort(unique(df$var1)), server = TRUE)
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'var2', choices = sort(unique(df$var2)), server = TRUE)
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'var3', choices = sort(unique(df$var3)), server = TRUE)

  filterData <- function(dataset){
    df <- dataset
    if (!is.null(input$var1)){
      df <- df[which(df$var1 == input$var1),]
    }
    if (!is.null(input$var2)){
      df <- df[which(df$var2 == input$var2),]
    }
    if (!is.null(input$var3)){
      df <- df[which(df$var3 == input$var3),]
    }
    df
  }

  output$dt <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(filterData(df))
  })

  getwhich<-function(){
    whichs<-which(df$var3 == df$var3)

    if(!is.null(input$var1)){
      whichs<-intersect(whichs,which(df$var1 %in% input$var1))
    }
    if(!is.null(input$var2)){
      whichs<-intersect(whichs,which(df$var2 %in% input$var2))
    }
    if(!is.null(input$var3)){
      whichs<-intersect(whichs,which(df$var3 %in% input$var3))
    }
    return(whichs)
  }

  observe({
    w<-getwhich()
    if(is.null(input$var1)){
      updateSelectizeInput(session,"var1",choices=sort(unique(df$var1[w])))
    }

  })

  observe({
    w<-getwhich()
    if(is.null(input$var2)){
      updateSelectizeInput(session,"var2",choices=sort(unique(df$var2[w])))
    }

  })

  observe({
    w<-getwhich()
    if(is.null(input$var3)){
      updateSelectizeInput(session,"var3",choices=sort(unique(df$var3[w])))
    }

  })


})
```

Hope this helps.